# Windows: How to find file name for a file handle?

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, file-management

I'm working with a software called logstash that processes log files and stores the progress in a file like this:

```
82484791-1419-65536 0 0 26507948
82484791-1420-65536 0 0 26071030
82484791-1421-65536 0 0 3065829
82484791-1422-65536 0 0 3973980
82484791-1425-65536 0 0 4301931
```

I want to see the names of the files which have been processed.

According to documentation this is to be interpreted as:

> Sincedb files are text files with four columns:
>
> The inode number (or equivalent). The major device number of the file
>   system (or equivalent). The minor device number of the file system (or
>   equivalent). The current byte offset within the file.

On linux I can convert the inode to filename using:

```
find /path/to/mountpoint -inum <inode number>
```

or

```
debugfs -R 'ncheck <inode number>' /dev/sda2 2>/dev/null
```

What is the Windows equivalent to do this? **How do I convert the windows filehandle/file descriptors to file and directory names?**

Comment: @KshitizSharma - Software recomendations are not on topic.  I linked you to the API so you could write your own program.

Answer (score 2):

File descriptors and file handles are ephemeral: they exist only while a program is running, and can be reused. Finding them in a logfile is pretty pointless.

Linux inodes are *not* file descriptors. They're part of the on-disk file system structure in common file systems, such as Ext2 and Ext3. Since they're so important to Linux, Linux will simulate inode numbers when accessing a Microsoft FAT file system.

That gets us to the next problem: Windows doesn't use inodes, because typical Microsoft file systems do not use inodes. It's pretty unclear what the "or equivalent" value is. If I had to guess, I'd guess [Update Sequence Number(USN)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788042(v=ws.11).aspx) but don't take my word for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll be looking into USN. What ever is in that file must be permanent, because logstash supports resume functionality. That is, if it is stopped it can be started again and it will pick up processing from where it left (from same byte offset within the file).